# where and how to store personal access token?

Tags: azure-devops

I am having a problem in storing personal access token from Azure Devops.
The problem is that I have stored it in `App.config` and this is bundled in the  installer. And the people who will be downloading and installing the software will not do it every 3 months as PAT will be valid for 3 months. SO, I am looking for better architecture of the software.
One of the solution is to use Azure Key Vault, but it will comes with a cost.
Any ideas regarding this?

Comment: For what you using the PAT in your application?

Comment: I am using to download code.

Comment: This is a pretty insecure practice. I'd recommend to (regularly) publish your package/sources to Azure Blog Storage or similar location and download from there. You should never hand out PAT, **Personal** access tokens, to 3rd parties.